# Unable to launch applications via GUI

Tags: command-line, gui, vlc, sublime-text

I have downloaded, installed - Sublime Text 3, RStudio, VLC, etc using the official procedures mentioned. If i access these programs via Terminal, by running their respective binaries, it works. However, via GUI - when I search for the applications - only VLC appears. So basically only way to run Sublime Text and RStudio for me is to access via Terminal. I have set the environment variable PATH in /etc/profile to directories that have binary files of these applications. Still problem persists. Surprisingly no one else has reported similar error before - of not being able to launch applications without CL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Create a 'application_name'.desktop file and save it in /usr/share/applications

Here is the format of the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version = <Version of the Application>
Name = <Name of the Apllication not the binary>
Exec=</path/to/binary>
Icon=</path/to/icon>
Terminal=False
Type=Application
Categories=<whatever the application falls into>
```

Enter the respective Names , binary and icons except the < and >

EDIT:

[Here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html) is an example of desktop file as @Zanna pointed out.

Comment: there's an example for a .desktop file for sublime [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html)

Comment: Well I was unaware of that , thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Didn't know significance of .desktop files till now.